# Disassemble Windows PE .data section

Tags: python, assembly, disassembly, portable-executable

I'm trying to disassemble Windows PE32 files using Python, but based on the output I'm not sure if i'm doing it correctly.

Currently I'm trying to disassemble the .data section of a PE file with pefile and capstone library.

```
import pefile
from capstone import *

def disassemble(fpath):
    pe = pefile.PE(fpath)
    for s in pe.sections:
        print(s.Name)
        md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_32)
        for j in md.disasm(s.get_data(), pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.ImageBase + s.VirtualAddress):
            print("0x%x:\t%s\t%s" % (j.address, j.mnemonic, j.op_str))
```

I expected (in the .data section) the output to be something like

```
.data 
example_var    DW    12345
example_var2   DB    'c'
...
```

but instead it outputs assembly in the format of

```
<addr>     <instr>    <opstr>
0x4b601a   add        byte ptr [eax], al
```

Is there any way of getting the output I'm looking for, or is that not possible and if so then why? It also must be disassembled through Windows and not Linux

Comment: Diassembling is not the same thing as readong a binary file type.

Comment: @BaileyKocin so is this the correct output to expect or is there a more accurate way to disassemble the executable?

Comment: If you are "disassembling" you ate going to get the assembly version of the PE executable. If you are parsing a binary file type with a module like struct you would get what you expect.

Comment: Oh i see, is there an efficient way of reading binary files on windows on the command line or python. I've tried pev and peexplorer but I need something to generate something like the original assembly without manually doing it. Also comparing it to the original assembly, what are the downsides to disassembling just the .data section?

Comment: There's no way for the disassembler to know that the content of the section you've given it is supposed be data rather than code. It just assumes it's supposed to code, because that's what disassemblers do. They turn binary machine code into assembly to make easier for humans to read.  There's also no way from the section contents alone to know what a given byte is supposed to be for or what symbol, if any, it was given in the original source code. Otherwise you can just turn it a series of DB statements easily enough yourself.

Comment: @RossRidge this might be a stupid question, but in the original assembly the .data section is usually marked as far as i know with `section .data`. Is this header lost in the compilation? I assume all the .data would exist in a specific range of memory and you could somehow retrieve it if you knew the addresses?

Comment: That's what `s.get_data()` does when `s` is the `.data` section.  But the value returned is just a byte string, an array of bytes, just like when `s` is the `.text` section.  `md.disasm()` has no reason to treat the two byte strings any different, both because it can't tell the difference and because its job is to disassemble machine code, not data.

Comment: Without a symbol table, the disassembler won't even be able to tell the which bytes are part of a `dw` and which are part of a `db`.